# Getting the below error while using ng2-pdf-viewer in my angular 12 app. while running the storybook.Not able to see the pdf file display in storybook

Tags: typescript, pdf, angular12

```
**Error:**
Error: Cannot find module 'pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf
    
**HTML File**

 <pdf-viewer
      [src]="pdfSrc"
      [render-text]="true"
      [original-size]="false"
      style="width: 800px; height: 600px"
    ></pdf-viewer> 

 **TS FILE**

pdfSrc = "../../assets/documents/design-system.pdf";

 **MODULE FILE**
```

import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';
imports: [
PdfViewerModule
]

```
    **STORYBOOK TS FILE**
```

import { moduleMetadata } from "@storybook/angular";
import { DesignSystemComponent } from "src/app/design-system/design-system.component";
import { Story, Meta } from '@storybook/angular/types-6-0';
import { AppModule } from "../../src/app/app.module";

export default {
title: 'Components/DesignSystems/Variants',
component: DesignSystemComponent,
decorators: [
moduleMetadata({
imports:[AppModule]
})
],
} as Meta;

const Template: Story = (args: DesignSystemComponent) => ({
component: DesignSystemComponent,

});

export const Variants = Template.bind({});

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The issue is resolved by updating the versions as :     "ng2-pdf-viewer": "6.3.2",
    "@types/pdfjs-dist": "2.1.7",
    "pdfjs-dist": "2.5.207".